# Togglez feature activation based on input parameters from call

Tags: java, togglz

All the `ActivationStrategy` of togglez uses input from HttpRequest or from other context.

However, If I am using togglez for stand alone java application is there any way to pass parameters into `isActive` method.

```
Features.DOWNLOAD_ACCESS.isActive(availableBalance);
```

instead of

```
Features.DOWNLOAD_ACCESS.isActive();
```

Below is `ReleaseDateActivationStrategy` uses current date. But if some one change system date than it will fail.
https://github.com/togglz/togglz/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/togglz/core/activation/ReleaseDateActivationStrategy.java

Comment: Did you get the solution? What was the final approach?

Comment: No, i was thinking about the case only, we haven't looked for more customization.

Comment: Oh. Ok. In my case, togglz isActive method is called inside Async block, and  I am not able to get SpringSecurityContext in there. So was thinking to pass userId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActivationStrategies in Togglz have an IsActive method take two parameters, the FeatureState and a FeatureUser. These are supplied by a StateRepository implementation and a UserProvider implementation respectively. 
If you want to have that level of customization in stand alone applications you should provide and implement a custom FeatureManagerProvider which provides the feature manager as described in the [Togglz advanced config](https://www.togglz.org/documentation/advanced-config.html). You create a custom StateRepository and UserProvider as well.

Comment: It is not about user id only. See edited question. If you want to restrict download feature for user based on available data balance. And this data balance is not available from UserProvider.

Comment: In that case I would recommend implementing a custom StateRepository to get that information into the FeatureState. You cannot simply add additional parameters to the isActive method as it is an implementation of the Feature interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your existing `UserProvider` implementation and augment the `FeatureUser` with any additional attributes:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TogglzConfig {

    private final TogglzProperties properties;


    //... 

    @Bean
    public UserProvider userProvider() {
        return new SpringSecurityUserProvider(properties.getConsole().getFeatureAdminAuthority()) {
            @Override
            public FeatureUser getCurrentUser() {
                SimpleFeatureUser user = (SimpleFeatureUser)super.getCurrentUser();
                user.setAttribute(
                        "availableBalance", 
                        getAvailableBalance()); // Implement this logic                          
                return user;
            }
        };
    }
}
```